# Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

When I installed cocoa pods I got this message. The cocoa pods downloaded is in version 1.10.1. Ive tried to use the command they give but this appears:

Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

Does it means that the latest version available is 1.13.1 but I can't use it because of a problem? How to solve it?

Comment: You need to install rbenv and get control of your Ruby before trying to use pods.

Answer (score 111):

This solved the issue for me

```sh
brew install cocoapods
```

should already be linked (as pointed out by Raphael Pinel) but if you want to make sure run

```sh
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Comment: This actually fixed it for me too.

Comment: Worked like a charm, @Mohammed Salman!
However, NOT A SOLUTION but a Workaround.
Still, a #thumbsup since I wanted to save time right now.

Comment: It seems that the second command `brew link --overwrite cocoapods` is not necessary. I got `Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.0` after running it. So `brew install cocoapods` seems to be enough to update

Comment: I was getting the exactly same error that OP and when trying `gem install ffi` I was getting:
`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
`

So, doing it that you said worked for me, thanks!

Comment: ran this then ran `sudo gem pristine --all`

Comment: does not works for me :(

Comment: Doesn't works for me

Answer (score 62):

Basically, you need to do what the warning message says: install the Gem "ffi" in the specified version by running `gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1`. However, usually you don't have write permissions on the system to install a Gem into the stated directory.

You could probably just use `sudo`, i.e. run the command `sudo gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1` and enter the password, but I guess this is generally not recommended as it is a security risk.

I installed it like this:

```
gem install ffi --version 1.13.1 --user-install
```

Then I had to add the installation path to my `PATH` variable; in my case I added this line to my `~/.zshrc`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:$PATH
```

I'm really not an expert on Ruby stuff, but this solved the issue for me.

Comment: I did it several times, and still gave me the same error.

Comment: It worked for me. I did: 
 sudo gem install ffi --version 1.15.5 --user-install

Then added this to  my ~/.bashrc

export PATH=$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 37):

This worked for me :

> `sudo gem pristine ffi` (don't write a version here, because it will fix the problem of all versions)

then :

> `pod install`

Comment: The contents of the brackets here is what was important for me!

Answer (score 19):

MacOS: Ventura v13.0

Updating the Ruby version worked like a charm. Did the following steps.

```
$ brew install rbenv
```

Installed the latest ruby version.

```
$ rbenv install 3.1.2
```

To activate the above version as global default version.

```
$rbenv global 3.1.2
```

To install ffi

```
$ sudo gem install ffi --version 1.15.5 --user-install
```

Comment: Needed the same steps after upgrading to Sonoma as well.

Answer (score 12):

None of the answers worked for me. So, I thought of uninstalling all versions of ruby which I had unknowingly installed, and keeping only the one installed by Xcode.

```
brew uninstall --force ruby
```

Then, uninstalled cocoapods

```
brew uninstall --force cocoapods
```

I was left with the ruby installed by XCode. I ran:

```
gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.3
```

I realised the other versions got installed in `~/.local`

I deleted the whole folder as it had nothing other than the old `gem` folder

```
rm -rf ~/.local
```

Now, reinstall cocoapods:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Try running:

```
pod install
```

OR

```
gem -v
```

You should not see this error.

This usually happens when you have multiple gem versions installed and the path is incorrect.

*P.S I am using macOS Monterey 12.1*

Comment: Awesome I finally managed to fix that bug thanks to you! Thanks

Comment: After trying all the other fixes this one worked for me. I did it like this: ```brew uninstall cocoapods```, ```brew uninstall ruby```, ```brew install cocoapods```. After that the error went away. This error first appeared after ```brew upgrade``` that updated cocoa pods to 1.14.2. I think the problem is some confusion between the default ruby and the brew ruby.

Answer (score 9):

in my case ( **mbpm1 pro** ) , my other project are fine , but some project from my friend ( windows only) i got some issue , i fixed by

1. `arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi`
2. `flutter clean` dont forget to clean after installing some gem
3. `flutter pub get` re get
4. run now  ( these run would automatically run pod install ) just click on main.dart ( vscode )

Answer (score 6):

My issue was that the pre installed ruby had those extensions installed and caused the error messages. Run the command below to
see all installed packages. Said command should also print the error `Ignoring ... because its extensions are not built`. Directly reference `/usr/bin/gem` since you might have ruby installed via brew which would be called otherwise.

```
/usr/bin/gem list
```

Then manually uninstall all mentioned extensions for the default ruby.

```
sudo /usr/bin/gem uninstall ffi
```

Comment: This one is the one that worked for me when nothing else would. I'm on macOS Monterey 12.6.1 on a M1 machine

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had paths mismatch, this command helped me:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

Also check paths order in you *.zshrc* file

f.e.

```
# Ruby
export PATH="~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"

# User local
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

`gem install cocoapods`

This is a workaround and not a solution, but for me, after trying all other posted solutions (on Monterey 13.0.1, I traced it back to it seemingly picking the homebrew installed cocoapods picking up the ffi library from ~/.rbenv/shims, with the only timely work around being to install cocoapods via gem, per above.

All this said, I don't claim to be well versed in rbenv, or any other dependency manager, for that matter.

I'd love to know a better answer that didn't bork the homebrew based installation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used Xcode Version 14.3.1, after `sudo gem pristine ffi` command it still doesn't resolved the issue, then again I have to do the following changes in Xcode too. then problem resolved.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Start the Terminal on a Mac M1 with Rosetta and run

```
pod update
```