# Pod Install: Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, installation, cocoapods

I tried running `pod install` in my Xcode project, but got the following error

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'ffi' (>= 1.3.0) among 84 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/dylan/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
```

When I ran `gem env`, I got

```
    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/dylan/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/dylan/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-20
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/dylan/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Everything was working before, one thing I did recently was updating Xcode to 12.3 and Big Sur. Not sure everyone else has this issue.

Comment: There’s your problem: “INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0”. You need to stop using the system ruby and install your own. See my article https://www.biteinteractive.com/how-to-get-started-with-pods/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698820/ignoring-ffi-1-13-1-because-its-extensions-are-not-built-try-gem-pristine-ffi)

Answer (score 8):

Got the same problem after updating to Big Sur

Reinstalling cocoapods works for me

```
gem install cocoapods
```

If you got the following error,

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

install this

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xcode-select --install
```

This is worked for me, before updating your pod please run the above line, then use your pod update or install

Answer (score 0):

try `brew install cocoapods` if you use brew. then `brew link --overwrite cocoapods`