# can't run flutter project on iOS simulator

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator, flutter-ios

I have been developing e-commerce app for about 3 months, I switched to MacOs recently.
I have a problem when I run my code in iOS Simulator
every time I run it I get this message.

```
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    Ignoring ffi-1.15.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.4
    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in `stack'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in `report'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:173:in `repo_information'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:77:in `stack'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:24:in `report'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.15.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

note:

*my project works fine on a real device and android emulator.

*I only can't run this project on iOS simulator other projects work fine when I run it on iOS simulator

so I don't know what the problem is, am I having problem with iOS folder in my project?

I tried every possible way and still not found a solution.

any ideas?

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with your "ruby" or "cocoapods".
Try to re-install both "ruby" and "cocoapods" if you're okay with it. Or, you could try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698820/ignoring-ffi-1-13-1-because-its-extensions-are-not-built-try-gem-pristine-ffi

Comment: how can I install "ruby" or "cocoapods". can you please help?

Comment: @MuhamadJabaly 1) Open your terminal 2) run this 'sudo gem install cocoapods' 3) if it ask user passwords then enter your system password and hit enter.   ====> By this you can install cocoapods in your system and after this please try again your issue

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: no sir I didn't, and the deadline for this assignment is so close I don't know what to do

Answer (score 31):

I had the same issue when moving from an Intel based Mac to a ARM (M1 Pro) based mac and working with Flutter.

1. Run this command to find all CocoaPods Components `gem list --local | grep cocoapods` Then for each version/component you want to **uninstall each one**.
2. `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
3. `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core`
4. `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader`
5. `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-deintegrate`
6. Once each dependancy is uninstalled - install the ARM version of the ffi package: `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
7. Install the rest of the CocoaPods using the ARM version `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install cocoapods`

You should now be able to build using Flutter and Xcode.

Thanks to @Datasun

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644365/cocoapods-on-m1-apple-silicon-fails-with-ffi-wrong-architecture)

Comment: thanks for your help, but I am the installation is getting failed when I Install the rest of the CocoaPods using the ARM version, idk why please if you think you can help I will be glad to you

Comment: Are you using an ARM based Mac?

Comment: no, I am using m1

Comment: Worked for me, thank you!

Comment: @MuhamadJabaly M1 is an ARM-based Mac ;-)

Comment: `arch -x86_64` installs the *Intel* version, using Rosetta 2, not the ARM version as currently stated

Comment: This solved it for me!

Answer (score 16):

Use these two commands to get the latest ffi and pod(your project library) dependency for **x86-64** architecture CPU then **Rosetta** will handle this automatically to convert the **x86-64(Intel-based CPU) instructions set to ARM instruction set which basically uses inside the Apple Silicon Chip M1 family**

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: This solved the problem in my M1, just remember to run at least the second command inside the Xcode project folder of the Flutter project

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1. Go to your applications > utilities folder.
2. Right click and click "Get Info" on your terminal app
3. Check "Open Using Rosetta" option
4. Start your terminal app
5. `sudo gem install cocoapods`
6. `sudo gem install ffi`
7. `pod install`

Originally from here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10220