# How do I fix Ignoring ffi-1.15.3 because its extensions are not built

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm using CocoaPods 1.10.2. And when I type `pod --version` in my terminal, I'm getting the following warning:

> Ignoring ffi-1.15.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.3

How could I fix this?

Comment: This error occurs when the ruby version is updated. 

I You can installed it like this:

gem install ffi --version 1.15.3 --user-install

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698820/ignoring-ffi-1-13-1-because-its-extensions-are-not-built-try-gem-pristine-ffi

Comment: Wow..!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this solution worked.

Download and install Homebrew using the following method:
Open terminal and paste in the following command string:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

And please install cocoapods.

```
brew install cocoapods
```